# How to resolve the StaleElementReferenceException in selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox

I was trying to create an automation tool using selenium with python which searches google for a particular link and if the link is in the top results it will be marked as indexed and if it is not present it will be marked as not indexed. The first link gets searched with no problem but when I target the search bar to search the next link I'm getting this error. I'm looping over all my links in my database.

Below given is the code I used for searching google.

**parser/parser.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from indexer.models import Link
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def main():
    indexed = 0
    not_indexed = 0

    db_links = Link.objects.all()

    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)

    visited_google = False

    for link in db_links:
        try:
            if not visited_google:
                driver.get(f"https://www.google.com")
                visited_google = True
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='APjFqb']")))
            textarea = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//textarea[@id='APjFqb']")
            textarea.send_keys(link.link)
            textarea.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator=(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='search']")))
            search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//div[@id='search']")
            anchor = search.find_element(By.XPATH, value=f"//a[@href='{link}']")
            if anchor:
                indexed += 1
            else:
                not_indexed += 1
        except NoSuchElementException:
            not_indexed += 1
    driver.quit()
    print(indexed)
    print(not_indexed)
```

I am using django. My view function is like this

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from .parser.parser import main
def parse(req):
    if req.method == "POST":
        if not req.POST["links"]:
            return Http404("Bad Request")
        else:
            email = req.POST["email"]
            links = req.POST["links"]
            uid = math.floor(time.time())
            main()
            return HttpResponse("parsing")
    else:
        return Http404("Error")
```

This is the error I am getting

```
StaleElementReferenceException at /parse/
Message: The element reference of <textarea id="APjFqb" class="gLFyf" name="q" type="search"> is stale; either its node document is not the active document, or it is no longer connected to the DOM; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
StaleElementReferenceError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:461:5
element.resolveElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:509:11
deserializeJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:206:33
cloneObject@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:56:24
deserializeJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:213:16
json.deserialize@chrome://remote/content/marionette/json.sys.mjs:217:10
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:85:30
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have `StaleElementReferenceException`, because after pressing `Enter` you don't wait until page would be re-rendered, so you got into two states when element was inited while page was still in previous search result state.
Then page is rendered, and previous result is not exist anymore.
So, you should wait until your page is re-rendered.

Possible solution is to wait that first link element is Stale (not exist in DOM) after clicking Enter.

```py
    #previous code
    visited_google = False

    first_link = None
    for link in db_links:
        try:
            if not visited_google:
                driver.get(f"https://www.google.com")
                visited_google = True
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='APjFqb']")))
            textarea = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//textarea[@id='APjFqb']")
            textarea.clear()
            ActionChains(driver).click(textarea).send_keys(link.link).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
            if first_link:
                wait.until(EC.staleness_of(textarea))
            first_link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#center_col a')))
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator=(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='search']")))
            search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//div[@id='search']")
            anchor = search.find_element(By.XPATH, value=f"//a[@href='{link}']")
            if anchor:
                indexed += 1
            else:
                not_indexed += 1
        except NoSuchElementException:
            not_indexed += 1

    driver.quit()
    print(indexed)
    print(not_indexed)
```

In code I added clearing input and replaced `send_keys` to `send_keys` from `ActionChains`.
If it would be not stable enough, you can add additional wait / wait for other stale element in google search output (or even perform implicit wait if you don't care about code quality)